# Add Dashing Gem dashboard to existing rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, dashing

I have a rails app I've been developing on the Cloud 9 IDE. I've been looking for the best solution for a user dashboard once someone authenticates to Devise. Dashing looks awesome.

How do I install the gem and create a new dashboard, without having to create a whole new rails project? I can't have two apps running in the same c9 workspace, so I need to create a new dashboard in my existing application so I can connect to my db, etc... right?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dashing [`dashing-rails`](https://rubygems.org/gems/dashing-rails/versions/2.5.0) gem with which you can run dashboard using rails app.

[github page](https://github.com/gottfrois/dashing-rails) of `dashing-rails`. Also [here is an issue](https://github.com/gottfrois/dashing-rails/issues/26) that deals with integrating `dashing-rails` with an existing rails app.